# I am unable to pass on the value to a PHP script from a javascript using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

What is it that I am doing wrong? the value of myid1 is not being accepted by my PHP script. My Javascript code is below followed by my PHP script. Please help.

Javascript code

```
    function generaterepno(selectedid) {
     var idnum=selectedid;
     var idnum1=idnum.split(":",1);
     var text='[{"myid1":idnum1}]';
     var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var url = "reportnumber.php";
     httpc.open("POST", url, true); // sending as POST

     httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", text.length);

     httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { 
     if(httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { 
      alert(httpc.responseText);
      var myArr = JSON.parse(httpc.responseText);             
     }
     httpc.send(text);
     document.getElementById('genno').value=idnum1;
    }
```

My PHP is as follows-

```
    <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    $mynewid=$_POST["myid1"];
    $mynewid=strip_tags($mynewid);

    include("inc_con.php");
    $myquery="SELECT MAX(report_number) AS mrepno FROM childreports WHERE child_id='$mynewid' ORDER BY report_number";
    $myresult=mysql_query($myquery);
    if(!$myresult) {
    $outp = '[{"reportn":"0"}]';
    echo ($outp);
    die('records do not exist');
    }
    $outp = "[";
    while($rm = mysql_fetch_array($myresult)) {
    $outp .= '{"reportn":"'.$rm["mrepno"].'"}';
    }
    $outp .="]";

    mysql_close($con);

    echo ($outp);

    ?>
```

I am a newbie to JSON and Javascript. Been trying to learn it on my own by reading. The alert message of the responseText is displaying a notice that myid1 is not defined. Also in my Javascript the HTML id genno is supposed to get the the return value from PHP code that is the max report number as obtained from the SQL query. Once I get reportn variable with some value I can JSON parse it and put it in the genno id but my problem is sending the myid1 value properly to my PHP script reportnumber.php.

Can someone help please? Thanks!

After prompt and great help from Kyle I made some changes in my Javascript function as follows and my query appears in the comments section below.

```
    function myFunction(arr) {
     var tempans = arr.reportn;
     var myans = 0;
     if(tempans.length == 0) {
     var asknum = prompt('Enter previous report number:');
     myans = parseInt(asknum)+1;
     } else {
     myans = parseInt(tempans)+1;
     }
     document.getElementById('genno').value=myans;
    }
```

Why am i prompted TWICE for a user input?

Comment: whats the json that gets pushed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem here. `var text='[{"myid1":idnum1}]';` is not valid JSON because you're trying to put the variable idnum1 inside the string. It would be easier to set it in an object and then use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to JSON.

```
var text = JSON.stringify({"myid1": idnum1});
```

In PHP, you then need to decode it from the request body as it won't be set in $_POST.

```
$contents = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$myNewId  = $contents['myid1'];
```

Comment: now i am getting the notice 'Array to string conversion error' with $myNewId. Isn't $myNewId a single value now from the $contents array with myid1 index?

Comment: Ah. I didn't see that you assigned `idnum1` to an array in the javascript. You probably want `var idnum1=idnum.split(":",1)[0]` or `var idnum1=idnum.split(":",1)[1]` depending on what idnum is.

Comment: Now I have another slight problem! I have got the value from the query that is successfully executed and I can JSON.parse it too. I want to now check the value from this JSON.parse and see if it is null or not and if null I want to prompt the user for the earlier report number. The user is prompted for the earlier report number if the length of the returned value is 0 but the user is being prompted TWICE!!! Can't figure out why. Need help.

Comment: Honestly, I would remove the whole part where you are manually building the json string in php. Just make the array and call `json_encode()` on it. No need to make json by hand. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Will keep that in mind! Your answer was truly useful!